# Random gradient header generator

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

I made a header generator that creates a linear gradient of two random colors from its top left to its bottom right.

Please tell me about everything I could do better, but especially how to calculate and not hardcode the randomly shifted second array `secondColor`, that has the `minColorValue`, `maxColorValue` and the random value on other positions.

```js
const settings = {
  width: 500,
  height: 180,
  minColorValue: 70, // min rgb value
  maxColorValue: 185, // max rgb value
};
let container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
let firstColor = [0, 0, 0];
let secondColor = [0, 0, 0];

let create = function(width, height) {
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  container.appendChild(canvas);
};

let colorPicker = function() {
  // possible configurations of which of the rgb values is min, which is max, and which is inbetween
  let configurations = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 2, 1],
    [1, 0, 2],
    [1, 2, 0],
    [2, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 0],
  ];
  let randomConfig = configurations[random(0, 5)];
  firstColor[randomConfig[0]] = settings.minColorValue;
  firstColor[randomConfig[1]] = settings.maxColorValue;
  firstColor[randomConfig[2]] = random(settings.minColorValue, settings.maxColorValue);

  // shift configuration by one or two to never get a different second color
  let shiftAmount = random(1, 2);
  let secondConfig = [0, 0, 0];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    if (i + shiftAmount < 3) {
      secondConfig[i] = randomConfig[i + shiftAmount];
    } else {
      secondConfig[i] = randomConfig[i - 3 + shiftAmount];
    }
  }
  secondColor[secondConfig[0]] = settings.minColorValue;
  secondColor[secondConfig[1]] = settings.maxColorValue;
  secondColor[secondConfig[2]] = random(settings.minColorValue, settings.maxColorValue);

};

let fill = function() {
  let canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, settings.width, settings.height);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, `rgb(${firstColor[0]},${firstColor[1]},${firstColor[2]})`);
  gradient.addColorStop(1, `rgb(${secondColor[0]},${secondColor[1]},${secondColor[2]})`);
  context.fillStyle = gradient;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, settings.width, settings.height);
};
let start = function() {
  create(settings.width, settings.height);
  colorPicker();
  fill();
};

// help function
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #1d1f21;
}

canvas {
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.textbox {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>random gradient header</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body onload="start()">
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="textbox">Reload to get a different header gradient.</div>
  <script src="short.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please tell me about everything I could do better, but especially how to calculate and not hardcode the randomly shifted second array [...].

I suggest to get a random permutation of `[0, 1, 2]` by introducing a simple but unbiased [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) function.

A circular shift of that random permutation can then be found by mapping index `i` to index `(i + shift) % length`:

```
// Return two shifted colors with min, max and random component:
function randomGradientColors(min, max) {
  let permutation = shuffle([0, 1, 2]);
  let shift = random(1, 2);
  return [
    permutation.map(i => [min, max, random(min, max)][i]),
    permutation.map(i => [min, max, random(min, max)][(i + shift) % 3])
  ];
}
```

Since you asked for *everything* that you could do better, I would like to suggest using a CSS background gradient instead of a canvas element. If compatibility is not a concern, you can even leverage fancy [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables):

```
.gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--from, black), var(--to, black));
}
```

Your markup then would provide the `min` and `max` color components via data attributes:

```
<div class="gradient" data-min="70" data-max="185"></div>
```

And your script would simply query all `.gradient` elements and compute their CSS `from` and `to` variables from the provided data attributes:

```
let gradients = document.querySelectorAll(".gradient");
for (let gradient of gradients) {
  let [from, to] = randomGradientColors(
    gradient.dataset.min,
    gradient.dataset.max
  );
  gradient.style.setProperty("--start", "rgb(" + from + ")");
  gradient.style.setProperty("--to", "rgb(" + to + ")");
}
```

This approach is pretty flexible and allows you to adapt the styling to your needs without touching the script.

Here is the complete code:

```js
// Return random integer within interval [min, max]:
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// Shuffle array in-place:
function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}

// Return two shifted colors with min, max and random component:
function randomGradientColors(min, max) {
  let permutation = shuffle([0, 1, 2]);
  let shift = random(1, 2);
  return [
    permutation.map(i => [min, max, random(min, max)][i]),
    permutation.map(i => [min, max, random(min, max)][(i + shift) % 3])
  ];
}

// Compute CSS 'from' and 'to' variables for all gradients:
let gradients = document.querySelectorAll(".gradient");
for (let gradient of gradients) {
  let [from, to] = randomGradientColors(
    gradient.dataset.min,
    gradient.dataset.max
  );
  gradient.style.setProperty("--from", "rgb(" + from + ")");
  gradient.style.setProperty("--to", "rgb(" + to + ")");
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #1d1f21;
}

.gradient {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 180px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--from, black), var(--to, black));
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.textbox {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gradient" data-min="70" data-max="185"></div>
</div>
<div class="textbox">Reload to get a different header gradient.</div>
```

If you wish to support older browsers, remove the CSS variables and use

```
gradient.style.background = 
  "linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(" + from + "), rgb(" + to + "))";
```